# Which set of response links should I use when responding to a meeting invitation in Gmail/Google Apps Email?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

When I receive an e-mail invitation via Google Apps, there are two places where it asks if I'm going, and I'm never sure which one to click (see screenshot).  Does it matter which one I click?  What's the difference, and why does it always ask twice?

[image: meeting invitation in Gmail/Google Apps]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. The reason there are 2 is because top response is a Gmail add-on that recognizes a Google Calendar invitation, and then displays a Calendar widget to make it easier for you to reply.

The second is the actual invitation email message, which does include RSVP links in the body text. The reason you see both is just that Gmail will add the widget automatically. If you invite a non-Gmail user, they will only see the email body text, and will have to use those links.

My personal preference is to use the top links for 2 reasons:

1. Clicking on the top link will highlight the RSVP selection in bold and will remember the choice if you open the email again. It's also more convenient to view your agenda as you respond.
2. Clicking on the top link will let you respond in the email itself quickly and let you move on to other email. Clicking the bottom link will open a new tab and take you to Calendar, which is inconvenient when all I want to do is respond quickly and be done with it. I get no new information when forced into Calendar.